# Save more than one string using OutputStreamWriter

Tags: android, storage, outputstream

In my app the user taps the screen to gain score. And then with that score they can buy upgrades. I want to be able to save three integer values :Counter,add,singleclick. I know how to save the first integer value Counter, but when I copy and paste the same method and replace the Counter integer with the add integer it doesn't work. Can you guys show me how to save the other integer values.

Please and Thank You

```
public void writeCounttofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("countvalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(Counter));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private  int readCountFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int countervalue = 0;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("countvalue.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            countervalue = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return countervalue;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Which error message do you get, if any?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo no error message it just doesn't work. like if I press the button to increase the users score it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo I tried copying a pasting the read and write method and replacing it with the single-click and add integer values.